# Употребление числительных с глаголами

Tags: числительные, глаголы

На лесном озере ребята поплавали, позагорали, раза три поиграли в карты и два раза постреляли из "мелкашки" по пустым консервным банкам.

Есть ли в этом предложении ошибки?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На лесном озере ребята поплавали, позагорали, раза три сыграли в карты и пару раз постреляли из "мелкашки" по пустым консервным банкам.

Приставка ПО имеет значение "совершать действие в течение некоторого времени".
Лучше "три раза сыграли в карты", то есть три партии.

Два раза - точное количество, лучше "пару раз" - приблизительное количество.

Comment: Vera, в каком из двух предложений есть ошибка?  1. "Постой здесь и минут пять пооткрывай и позакрывай окно." 2. "Постой здесь и несколько раз пооткрывай и позакрывай окно."

Comment: Ошибка во втором предложении.  Правильно: "Постой здесь и несколько раз открой и закрой окно."  Приставка ПО обозначает действие в течение определенного времени, глагол с такой приставкой не может обозначать количество действий.

Comment: Спасибо, Vera !

Answer (score 3):

***На лесном озере ребята поплавали, позагорали, раза три поиграли в карты и два раза постреляли из "мелкашки" по пустым консервным банкам.***

Ошибок нет, если имеются в виду не два выстрела, а два подхода к стрельбе из "мелкашки".  Сколько было выстрелов, неизвестно.

Comment: По смыслу здесь речь идет именно о двух подходах к стрельбе, не о двух же выстрелах на всю компанию.